# Eclipse build script

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an Android app in eclipse with ADT.

How can I insert commands in the build proccess? Is it possible? I would like to copy some files from one project to another in each build, and I don't know where to copy the script to do this

Thanks!

Comment: what commands you want to insert ?

Comment: I think you can use ant or maven for this.

Comment: it's just cp from one folder to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Ant scripts instead of using ADT auto-build.